# Why are truth tables not circular?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Why are logical truth tables not circular? For example, let’s consider the task of defining the concept of implication. In fact, in using a truth table, we say that each combination of truth values *implies* another. So we are saying, for example, that *if* $P$ *and* $Q$, *then* $P\Rightarrow Q$, and so on for each possible truth combination. Is really the best way to define “$\Rightarrow$” as $$P\wedge Q\Rightarrow P\Rightarrow Q$$

$$P\wedge \lnot Q\Rightarrow \lnot(P\Rightarrow Q)$$

$$\lnot P\wedge Q\Rightarrow P\Rightarrow Q$$

$$\lnot P\wedge \lnot Q\Rightarrow P\Rightarrow Q$$

Therefore, I feel wary of using truth values to define logic because it seems to explicitly use that same logic in its construction. I suppose that this question further asks: how can logic really be defined, without using logic; for example, if we tried to define logic under a set of axioms, how would we ever be able to derive results regarding the nature of logic; that is to say, logic is the way we move from axioms to implications, how can we make implications about logic itself?

Comment: Your second line is not right. Need to switch the or on the left with and.

Comment: I am sorry; I meant all the or’s should be and’s...I will fix it now

Comment: We have a "natural logic" embedded in our language; we use it to formalize our way of reasoning with formal logic, symbolic logic and its modern form: mathematical logic. We cannot do otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your statements are not correct, for you are ***confusing material implication and logical implication.***

> P materially implies Q ( symbol $\rightarrow$) iff it is ( factually)
>   not the case that P istrue and Q is false ( or, equivalently, we are
>   ***factulally*** not in a case where P is true and Q is false).
>
> P logically implies Q ( symbol $\Rightarrow$) iff it is ( logically)
>   ***impossible*** that P is true while Q is false. ( or , equivalently, the case where P is true and Q is false is ***impossible***)

Hence there is no circularity. Truth tables and material implication belong to object language. The conclusions we draw in terms of what logically implies what belong to metalanguage, or to the metalogical level.

- Take for example your first formula  : $(P\wedge Q)\Rightarrow (P\Rightarrow Q)$.

It says that $(P\land Q)$ logically implies that " P logically implies Q" ( or, if you prefer, it says that $(P\land Q)$ logically implies that $(P\rightarrow Q)$ is a tautology ).

The following truth table shows that : the fact that $(P\rightarrow Q)$ is not false when $(P\land Q)$ is true ***does not make of $(P\rightarrow Q)$ a tautology***, that is a formula that is true in all 4 possible cases.

[image]

What is true, in fact,  is that : $(P\land Q)$ logically implies that P ***materially implies*** Q,

in symbols : $(P\wedge Q) \Rightarrow (P\rightarrow Q)$. ( The tautology is the central conditional, not the conditional embedded in the consequent).

- Let me show why your sentence is false by a counter example.

$(P\wedge Q)\Rightarrow (P\Rightarrow Q)$

$\equiv$ there is no possible case where ($(P\land Q)$ is true and  $(P\Rightarrow Q)$ is false )

$\equiv$ there is no possible case where  ( $(P\land Q)$ is true and there is a ***possible*** case in which $P$ is true and $Q$ is false)

But consider the case where both $P$ and $Q$ are true. In that case $(P\land Q)$ is true. This possible case certainly exists. But the fact that this case exists certainly does not prevent the ***possibility*** of the case where $P$ is true and $Q$ is false. !

- In terms of modal logic, with $\square X$ meaning " it is necessarily the case that X" :

(1) $\square [(P\land Q) \rightarrow ( P\rightarrow Q)]$

( In words : " necessarily ( P&Q implies that, if P, then Q)"  )

is correct , but is not the same thing as

(2) $\square [(P\land Q) \rightarrow \square ( P\rightarrow Q)]$

(In words : "necessarily ( P&Q implies that P necessarily implies Q)" ).

Note : on the distinction between material / logical implication, Lipschutz, *Outline Of Set Theory* (Chapter on the Algebra Of Proposiitons) ( At archive.org).

Answer (score 0):

All of math proceeds by postulating some set of axioms, and then writing out all of the logical conclusions that follow from those axioms. The truth tables just give the rules for what the valid deductive moves are in the game that is being played. You could change the rules, but then you would either be able to derive $P$ and $\neg P$ or there would be true statements you could not deduce in your system that would be true in the standard one, and your system would not be very helpful.

Comment: I completely agree. However, my questions is not what is the role of logic, rather it is precisely the way we “define” it. Regardless of what the actual truth values are, my point is that the process of defining - writing down - this truth table requires logic... exactly the same logic I am trying to formalize.

Comment: I see the truth table as a set of rules purely for manipulating symbols.  There is no "logic" to them, they are simply one set of rules among many.  I prefer them to other sets of rules because they do not create contradictions and provide me with useful results that I can publish and use to feed my kids.  Logic is just the manipulation of symbols to derive other arrangements of symbols that are useful or impress your colleagues, not an aesthetic or mystical experience.

Comment: (I am obviously in applied math).